# How to retrieve the earliest date from columns that have different dimensions?

Tags: sql

**DATA Explanation**

I have two data tables, one (PAGE VIEWS) which represents user events (CV 1,2,3 etc) and associated timestamp with member ID. The second table (ORDERS) represents the orders made - event time & order value. Membership ID is available on each table.

Table 1 - PAGE VIEWS (1,000 Rows in Total)

| Event_Day | Member ID | CV1 | CV2 | CV3 | CV4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/5/2021 | 115126 | APP | camp1 | Trigger | APP-camp1-Trigger |
| 11/14/2021 | 189192 | SEARCH | camp4 | Search | SEARCH-camp4-Search |
| 11/5/2021 | 193320 | SEARCH | camp5 | Search | SEARCH-camp5-Search |

Table 2 - ORDERS (249 rows in total)

| Date | Purchase Order ID | Membership Number | Order Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/12/2021 | 0088 | 183300 | 29.34 |
| 18/12/2021 | 0180 | 132159 | 132.51 |
| 4/12/2021 | 0050 | 141542 | 24.35 |

**What I'm trying to answer**

I'd like to attribute the CV columns (PAGE VIEWS) with the (ORDERS) order value, by the earliest event date in (PAGE VIEWS). This would be a simple attribution use case.

[Visual explanation of the two data tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7o6M.png)

**Issues**

I've spent the weekend result and scrolling through a variety of online articles but the closest is using the following query

```
Select min (event_day) As "first date",member_id,cv2,order_value,purchase_order_id
from mta_app_allpages,mta_app_orders
where member_id = membership_number
group by member_id,cv2,order_value,purchase_order_id;
```

The resulting data is correct using the DISTINCT function as Row 2 is different to Row 1, but I'd like to associate the result to Row 1 for member_id 113290, and row 3 for member_id 170897 etc.

| Date | member_id | cv2 | Order Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-01 | 113290 | camp5 | 58.81 |
| 2021-11-05 | 113290 | camp4 | 58.51 |
| 2021-11-03 | 170897 | camp3 | 36.26 |
| 2021-11-09 | 170897 | camp5 | 36.26 |
| 2021-11-24 | 170897 | camp1 | 36.26 |

[Image showing the results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etSjW.png)

I've tried using partition and sub query functions will little success. The correct call should return a maximum of 249 rows as that is as many rows as I have in the ORDERS table.

First-time poster so hopefully I have the format right.  Many thanks.

Comment: That's good info! What database (and version) are you using? Also add the DB tag too, as the sql tag info says do.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `RANK()` is the best approach:

```
select * from
     (
       select *, RANK()OVER(partition by membership_number order by Event_Day) as rnk
       from page_views as pv
       INNER JOIN orders as o
       ON pv.Member_ID=o.Membership_Number
     ) as q
where rnk=1
```

This will only fetch the minimum `event_day`.

However, you can use `MIN()` to achieve the same (but with complex `sub-query`):

```
select *
from 
(select pv.* 
from page_views as pv
inner join
       (
       select Member_ID, min(event_day) as mn_dt
       from page_views
       group by member_id
       ) as mn
   ON mn.Member_ID=pv.Member_ID and mn.mn_dt=pv.event_day
)as sq
INNER JOIN orders as o
ON sq.Member_ID=o.Membership_Number
```

Both the queries will get us the same answer.

See the **demo** in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba083b99d393f302ecef64313ff0cd39)*

Comment: Thank you very much. I was up to midnight last night trying to get my head around how to solve this. I managed to get this working if the data sat in the same table, but in most instances data sits in multiple tables and it was the joining logic as part of the same query that had me stumped. Many thanks again!